# How can I print Pascal's triangle without using factorial?

Tags: c

I have written a function that prints spaces in a row of the triangle, and another function that prints the numbers in that row. I have compiled the code, but for some reason it does not give the wanted output:

[image: Pascal's Triangle]

Here are my functions :

```
void print_pascal_triangle(int n)
{
   int i = 0;

   while (i <= n)
   {
    print_space(i, n);
    print_pascal_line(n);
    i++;
    printf("\n");
   }
}

void print_pascal_line(int i)
{
   int k = 0, num = 1; 

   printf("1");

   while (k < i)
   {
    num = (num *(i-k))/(k+1); 
    printf(" %d", num);
    k++; 
   }

}

void print_space(int i, int n)
{
    int space=i;
    while (space < n) 
   {
   printf(" ");
   space++;
   }
}
```

Here is the output I get when n=5:

[image: Output]

Comment: You'll get the right output when you print `print_pascal_line(i)`.

Comment: Don't post images of text! Code-formatting is sufficient to keep the indentation.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `print_pascal_line(i);` instead of `print_pascal_line(n);`